# Problema al guardar decimales en base de datos

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Estoy teniendo un problema en el trabajo y no logro reconocer que esta pasando, cree un campo decimal(10,2) null en una tabla de sql server...

en el codigo fuente tengo que calcular un porcentaje y guardar, calcular lo hace normal y al guardar salta un error predeterminado por el dev anterior, solo dice "ha ocurrido un error" y ninguna descripcion mas

el codigo fuente es algo asi

```
resultadoPureza.CantidadXKilo = (resultadoPureza.TotalOtrasEspecies * 1000) / viewModel.PesoInicialOtrasEspecies;

var analisisPurezaNidera = await unitOfWork.SolicitudSemillasAnalisis.Get(x =>
x.SolicitudID == resultadoPureza.SolicitudId && x.EnsayoSemillas != null &&
x.EnsayoID == resultadoPureza.EnsayoId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

if (analisisPurezaNidera != null) analisisPurezaNidera.Finalizado = true;

var guardado = await unitOfWork.Complete() > 0;
```

luego de pasar ese calculo llega a esta linea que genera el error

`var guardado = await unitOfWork.Complete() > 0;`

ese resultado venga con los decimales que venga no tienen que ser redondeados y en base de datos se tiene que guardar con 2 decimales pero aparentemente (segun mi interpretacion) al ser tan grande el numero sql genera un error

pero oh sorpresa que al revisar un codigo que es casi identico al mio se guarda sin problemas, por mas que le pase un numero exageradamente grande hace lo que yo busco

```
resultadoOtrasEspecies.CantidadPorKilo =
(resultadoOtrasEspecies.TotalOtrasEspecies * 1000) / viewModel.PesoInicial;

if(resultadoOtrasEspecies.CantidadPorKilo != null)
{
  await unitOfWork.SolicitudSemillasAnalisis.GuardarResultado(
  resultadoOtrasEspecies.SolicitudSemillas.SolicitudID, resultadoOtrasEspecies.EnsayoId,
  resultadoOtrasEspecies.CantidadPorKilo.ToString());
}

var guardado = await unitOfWork.Complete() > 0;
```

cuando uso metodos para redondear los calculos se guarda correctamente, incluso cuando uso string.format y le paso dos decimales tambien funciona, por eso interpreto que son la cantidad de decimales lo que falla

Comment: Como sabes que el error es de tipo de dato si el mensaje que te devuelve es sólo un *ha ocurrido un error*?

Comment: es lo que yo interprete, el problema viene cuando llega a la linea que marque, debugueando esa linea me lleva al viewbag para mostrarme el error

Comment: Es un error demasiado general, si te percatas en el código que si funciona el campo *CantidadPorKilo* se esta convirtiendo a `string` antes de guardarlo, por eso no falla. Pero reitero que el error es muy general; además hay cosas que no se saben como qué es lo que hace el método Complete de unitOfWork